# best practice for ssh connections from a program

Tags: paramiko

If I am writing a program (in my case a python program using paramiko) that executes multiple Tasks on a remote Server, for example, remove some files, then later run a program, then later move some files, is it better to make a single ssh Client and leave it open for the duration, or should I treat ssh Connections more like files and databases and open and Close them each time I execute a Task?